# PowerShell Custom Log Parsing

Tags: powershell, parsing, logging, scripting, filtering

I'm trying to figure out a efficient way to cycle through custom logs located in a custom location on a Windows Host. I've implemented some simple script's using select-sting cmdlets ion looping through the logs using for-each, but I'm looking to take a more sophisticated approach to this. P.S. I'm not PowerShell Savvy, so all this is a learning experience for me.

Essentially what should happen is that;

1. I have some common key words/strings available to me
2. These key words relate to a distinct issue
3. The script should cycle through the logs and search for the key word.
4. Once isolated, this should then generate an output based on the matched term's issue description

The logs are generic and will never change, so for each string that is matched it is pretty much known what the issue is and the output should provide a link to a fix.

Example Log's;

```
021-08-30T04:07:46Z E! message: send request failed, original error: Post "https://test.com/": dial tcp 172.31.11.121:443: i/o timeout
2021-08-30T04:07:46Z E! system: code: RequestError, message: send request failed, original error: Post "https://test.com/": dial tcp 172.31.11.121:443: i/o timeout
2021-08-30T02:15:46Z E! err:  AccessDenied: User: test is not authorized to perform: PutData status code: 403, request id: f1171fd0-05b6-4f7d-bac2-629c8594c46e
```

So far what I've come up with is possibly using two hash tables.

1. Hash table of matchers:errortypes as the key:value;

```
$errorList =@{
"AccessDenied"="permissions",
"i/o timeout"="connectivity"
}
```

2. The second hash table would then be a Hash table of errortypes:description as the key:value;

```
$errorDesc = @{                                                                        
"permissions"="The user does not have permission to perform the action, please reach out to your administrator",                                   
"connectivity"="The agent has failed to connect to one of the required endpoints. Please ensure the instance (and any proxy - if configured) is able to connect to all required endpoints. For more information on the required endpoints, please refer to https://helpmefixthis.com/"
}
```

Ideally, the script should cycle through the logs and see that the following log entry;

```
021-08-30T04:07:46Z E! message: send request failed, original error: Post "https://test.com/": dial tcp 172.31.11.121:443: i/o timeout
```

The above contains the string "i/o timeout", which is a key in the in the first hashtable, for which has a value - "connectivity". This should then refence the second hash table using this value "connectivity" for which is a key within this second table. The value assigned to this key should be the output, for example;

`The logs contained the following error "i/o timeout" which means that "The agent has failed to connect to one of the required endpoints. Please ensure the instance (and any proxy - if configured) is able to connect to all required endpoints. For more information on the required endpoints, please refer to https://helpmefixthis.com/"`

Maybe I'm going about this wrong or perhaps there is a better approach.

I have not attempted the above as I am not sure on where to even begin. I have implemented some simple scripts using basic select-string cmdlets and looping through each for the matched term's

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like this

```
$filename = "c:\temp\test.txt";
$pattern1 = "^(?<date>[^\s]+)\sE!\s(?<message>.*)";
$pattern2 = "^(?<type>[^:]+):(?<value>.*)"

$errors = Select-String -Path $filename -Pattern $pattern1

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

foreach($row in $errors.Matches)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $date = [DateTime]$row.Groups["date"].Value
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Date -NotePropertyValue $date

   $splitMessages = $row.Groups["message"].Value.Split(",");
   
   for($i = 0; $i -lt $splitMessages.Count; $i++)
   {
      write-host "split = " $splitMessages[$i]
      $splitMessages[$i] -match $pattern2
Write-Host $Matches
$Matches  | Format-Table
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ('type' + ($i + 1)) -NotePropertyValue $Matches.type
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ('message' + ($i + 1)) -NotePropertyValue $Matches.value
   }

   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}

$table
```

output

```
Date     : 8/30/0021 12:07:46 AM
type1    : message
message1 :  send request failed
type2    :  original error
message2 :  Post "https://test.com/": dial tcp 172.31.11.121:443: i/o timeout

Date     : 8/30/2021 12:07:46 AM
type1    : system
message1 :  code: RequestError
type2    :  message
message2 :  send request failed
type3    :  original error
message3 :  Post "https://test.com/": dial tcp 172.31.11.121:443: i/o timeout

Date     : 8/29/2021 10:15:46 PM
type1    : err
message1 :   AccessDenied: User: test is not authorized to perform: PutData status code: 403
type2    :  request id
message2 :  f1171fd0-05b6-4f7d-bac2-629c8594c46e
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read the log file(s) and filter the error values like this:

```
$errorList = @{
    'AccessDenied' = 'permissions'
    'i/o timeout'  = 'connectivity'
}

$errorDesc = @{                                                                        
    'permissions'  = 'The user does not have permission to perform the action, please reach out to your administrator'
    'connectivity' = 'The agent has failed to connect to one of the required endpoints. Please ensure the instance (and any proxy - if configured) is able to connect to all required endpoints. For more information on the required endpoints, please refer to https://helpmefixthis.com/'
}

$log = 'X:\Somewhere\TheLogFile.log'
$errorsFound = Get-Content -Path $log | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($key in $errorList.Keys) {
        if ($_ -match $key) {
            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                Error       = $key
                Description = $errorDesc[$errorList[$key]]
            }
            break
        }
    }
}

# view on console
$errorsFound | Format-List

# save this in a text file
$errorsFound | Format-List | Out-String | Set-Content -Path 'X:\Somewhere\TheErrors.txt'

# save this in a CSV file you can open in Excel
$errorsFound | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\TheErrors.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

On console this will output (using your example):

```
Error       : i/o timeout
Description : The agent has failed to connect to one of the required endpoints. Please ensure the instance (and any proxy - if configured) 
              is able to connect to all required endpoints. For more information on the required endpoints, please refer to https://helpmef
              ixthis.com/

Error       : i/o timeout
Description : The agent has failed to connect to one of the required endpoints. Please ensure the instance (and any proxy - if configured) 
              is able to connect to all required endpoints. For more information on the required endpoints, please refer to https://helpmef
              ixthis.com/

Error       : AccessDenied
Description : The user does not have permission to perform the action, please reach out to your administrator
```